# Angular 6 new project trying to add pwa gives error message

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I just created a new project with the name 'phoneBook' and when I try and execute the `ng add @angular/pwa` command I get an few seconds of install time and then an error with no meaning.

Error:

> Schematic input does not validate against the Schema: {"target":"build","configuration":"production","project":"phoneBook","title":"phoneBook"}
>   Errors:
>   Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(title).

I looked through the Angular@Cli issues and haven't found anything matching this error. I just updated my Angular cli to the latest version today.

```
ng -v

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 6.1.2
Node: 8.9.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.1.0
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.7.0
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.7.0
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.7.0
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.7.0
@angular-devkit/core              0.7.0
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.7.2
@angular/cli                      6.1.2
@angular/pwa                      0.6.8
@ngtools/webpack                  6.1.0
@schematics/angular               0.7.2
@schematics/update                0.7.2
rxjs                              6.3.2
typescript                        2.7.2
webpack                           4.9.2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please migrate your angular/cli with

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@6.2.1
```

This version is the highest reported by npmjs and this finally worked.

for more details also you can have a look on this [discussion](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11006)

Comment: So I need to downgrade my Angular CLI

Comment: what is your angular/cli version?

Comment: In question I have ng -v output. I am @CLI 6.1.2

Comment: try updating your cli to latest 6.1.7

Comment: I am going to try and force installing to the latest according to npm when I use the @latest for installing I don't get the highest version npm says

Comment: Alright we're in business I had to force the install to a specific version which npmjs reports as the highest version. Using the @latest didn't do the trick.

Comment: there's been issue with adding ng add angular/pwa, and there is solution which is working for beta version you can find here https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11465